# C# File.ReadAllText() not returning current file content

Tags: c#, json, file

I am having trouble reading a json config file from my filesystem. I am serializing an object to file like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Settings.Instance);
Directory.CreateDirectory(configFileDir);
File.WriteAllText(configFileDir + configFilePath, json);
```

The full path is

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\MyApp\config.json
```

Now I can read it with these lines:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(configFileDir + configFilePath);                
Instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(json);
```

My problem is that it seams that it won't correctly read some properties after I built a new version of the program. When I just restart, all the settings are loaded fine, but when I rebuilt, the file won't load longer string values (tokens).

A print of the json string shows empty string values for some keys which clearly have values when the file is opened in notepad.

Does anyone has a guess?

Greetings,
Maik

EDIT:

The json looks like this:

```
{
"DisplayLanguage": "en-US",
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjM4OWZmMTIxZWU1MmI1ZDk3NWEzY2E0NzYwN2JiZTIzODc1ZjViMDUxNzY1ZDE1MGExZDgyNTM0ODUyMjE4MTcxOGQ0ZTA2NTZlM2JhYzg5In0.eyJhdWQiOiJmNWIwYjcwMS01ODEzLTQ5OGMtYmE1NS1kMWZhOGM5YzQxMGUiLCJqdGkiOiIzODlmZjEyMWVlNTJiNWQ5NzVhM2NhNDc2MDdiYmUyMzg3NWY1YjA1MTc2NWQxNTBhMWQ4MjUzNDg1MjIxODE3MThkNGUwNjU2ZTNiYWM4OSIsImlhdCI6MTUzNzI4NDA0MCwibmJmIjoxNTM3Mjg0MDQwLCJleHAiOjE1Njg4MjAwNDAsInN1YiI6ImE1MTk2OTNjLTAzMGMtNDdjMi04MGI5LTZiNTc5YmQ3MzZlNSIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.yjzApeU54uXch-3V-x82V-mXfmyr-HG0LsxQMG74nrJP_dBmSi8MuB5mD3Zc07qRnmKnyep7YGYVdhvmukALIY4u5lXrVGXFx_U_EWMyEKce9BxMrM9qbqy-oZ5hfJ9rogUsKeQakkpnD4yciTqn0h8sg-uo6H0-pcWIubhWA9OYmU5-vAIhVRJrQBggW305auCiyKVYcoRQowf12RJhrudn8F_eOhEbrV4A9PZVHTIIVRRFFTCfcHNYDsW9cS1RJ07sOE_rg8-yjQt74gmClgZguYngjQiukCsJtzMBRywRUT24DPGauPsAyYHWzitfe-KaGBbUSLFr2YOK3cDhZI7POv6QaFH-iIcw2-2iTR_h2_rk_iVYQNsyv0lU9KglrsUjiAonqESyHvAyYcSVDaqRobDdG9iXSpKw4jDSL7vkt7_IkMQ1cCftvqueglDNosygR6zbmi4L7ESW5eia8n_6-q6tkSaPageupXXmEBMBZNQF_p8HQf9J8ma7hxc-bcPGFkHFFBhrWlTJg62fT9AR9wIq7zueYpamxkGgfZnXF9QMzEjXNobs3paF9pouTv7H6v1iHJ_90WpGe3NVnJTHxPWVImtb9npvfPgWcYE8Trz6xoTbE81Al5fLjrAK7antgS0DkYkzMp1rxSUQxw_qwTLywuFJJLcwhY5mY2s",
"GUID": "993bc5f2-0b2b-48da-8fc7-94a7b96dc322",
"sortedByRating": true,
"lists": ""
}
```

Only token and GUID seem to lose its values, DisplayLanguage and the others load just fine.
I print the json with log4net, this is not the problem.
I get the filepath with:

```
private static readonly string configFileDir = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%"), "Documents") + @"\MyApp";
private static readonly string configFilePath = @"\config.json";
```

Settings class looks like this:

```
public class Settings
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    private static readonly string configFileDir = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%"), "Documents") + @"\MyApp";
    private static readonly string configFilePath = @"\config.json";

    private static Settings _instance;

    public static Settings Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new Settings()); }
        private set { _instance = value; }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public static readonly string AddInVersion = "1.4.0.3";

    [JsonProperty("DisplayLanguage")]
    public static string DisplayLanguage { get; set; } = "";

    [JsonProperty("token")]
    public static string AuthToken { get; set; } = "";

    [JsonProperty("GUID")]
    public static string GUID { get; set; } = "";

    [JsonProperty("sortedByRating")]
    public static bool RecommendationsSortedByRating { get; set; } = true;

    [JsonProperty("DistLists")]
    public static string DistLists { get; set; } = "";

    public static void Load()
    {
        try
        {
            log.Info("trying to read config file: " + configFileDir + configFilePath);

            string json = File.ReadAllText(configFileDir + configFilePath);
            log.Info("read: " + json);

            Instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(json);
            log.Info("Config file loaded!");
            log.Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Instance, Formatting.Indented));

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            log.Info("Config file not found or could not be loaded. Using Default Settings");
        }
    }

    public static void Save(string settingToSave = "")
    {
        try
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Settings.Instance, Formatting.Indented);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(configFileDir);
            File.WriteAllText(configFileDir + configFilePath, json);
            log.Info("Config file successfully saved! (" + settingToSave + ")");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            log.Error("Config file could not be saved!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How long are these new string values?

Comment: How are you doing `print of the json string`?

Comment: Consider using `Path.Combine` to generate the full path of the file, instead of concatenating strings

Comment: see my edits for your questions

Comment: What does your Settings class look like?

Comment: It is pretty important to know what `Settings` looks like, post the code

Comment: Not sure if this would cause it, but why are all the serialized properties `static`? Your `Instance` object is an *instantiated object* and it should probably use *instance properties*. It is fine if just the Instance itself is static (singleton pattern).

Comment: Its pretty strange to have everything contained in one class like this, even stranger to have your properties all be `static`.  You should have a "Settings" POCO: A plain class that represents data and has no functionality and make sure your properties are _instance_ properties.  If you want singletons and serialization/deserializtion make those happen in _additional_ classes, **separate your concerns**

Comment: ok i will separate the model and the saving logic. Let me see if this fixes the isssue, but i feel not.

Comment: @MaikFruhner I know changing your code will fix the issue, [see here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6giv04)

Comment: If "string content_returned_from_ReadAllText != file content as I see in Notepad" is correct, I'd double check that you are using the correct path and that you did not call Save() during startup somehow. ReadAllText() will not modify you file content and will return the content of your settings file.

Comment: @MaikFruhner also, instead of this: `configFileDir + configFilePath` you should be using `Path.Combine()`

Comment: yea thanks for your advice. Splitting it up into two non static classes seems to do the trick. Turns out the quick and dirty solutions don't work at all in the end. Thx!

Answer (score -2):

It is not path issue  you are reading file very well.
check setting class

```
public class Settings{
public string DisplayLanguage{ get; set; }
public string token{ get; set; }

 }
```

if you miss any of them it can create issue. check formats also.
Log4net may not display long string. Try to check upper case  sentence case of token  in class.